# What's the best way to make a combination between static and dynamic content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need in Ruby on Rails a menubar with drop down facilities.
Almost everything is static except one.
There I need to display all categorys which the user has entered.

Do I need to use a Gem or Twitter Bootstrap for this or can this be done with a form helper ?

Roelof

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?
Assuming `user.categories` exists, and the `category` model have a `description` attribute.

```
<ul>
  <% user.categories.each do |cat| %>
    <li><%= cat.description %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This would create list items based on every category of the user.

Comment: I know this but how can I mixed this with this : <% form_for @entry do |f| %> 
  <%= f.text_field :name %> 
  <%= f.select :temperature, [['Hot','hot'],['Medium','medium'],['Cold','cold']] %> 
  <%= f.submit %> 
<% end %>